# tty screen reset on display zero

Tags: python, bash, shell

Loading screen at boot via .bashrc, overtime the screen output gets garbage,

Currently using screen -x (Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display mode)) to reset terminal/session on display 0

Looking for a .py or .sh script that will automate this process. Traditionally there is only 1 attached screen session at any given time.

Thinking:

```
#!/bin/bash
get_session=$(screen -list | grep tty1 | awk '{printf "%s", $1}')
```

OUTPUT = 14325.tty1.hostname

```
using OUTPUT to connect to session OR if connected to display 0 simply run screen -x to connect
```

Once connected to screen session need to perform a ctrl C to reset the screen.

Desired output is the active/attached tty1 session is reset.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
get_session=$(screen -list | grep tty1 | sed 's/[.].*$//' | awk '{printf "%s", $1}')
exec kill -INT $get_session
done
```